# Select records based on two tables where one column in one table starts with the records from another tables column using SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have one table that contains the prefix of Job Numbers. The other table contains the complete Job number as well as several of other columns of data. I would like to return the below result using sql.

Table 1

```
PfxJobNum
--------
001
006
024
```

Table 2

```
Id JobNum
--------
1 001aed
2 001bef
3 924bac
4 006aab
5 056bcb
6 084baa
```

Result

```
Id JobNum
--------
1 001aed
2 001bef
4 006aab
```

Comment: What's your dbms?

Comment: Both Microsoft Access and MySQL

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use a subquery with `exists .... like`

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table2 t1
WHERE exists (
 select 1
 FROM Table1 t2
 WHERE t1.JobNum like  t2.PfxJobNum +'%'
)
```

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=d7071fa3bc2396c3fcb66da55004b07a)

or use `CONCAT`

**Schema (MySQL v5.7)**

```
create table Table1(
   PfxJobNum varchar(50)
);



INSERT INTO Table1 VALUES ('001');
INSERT INTO Table1 VALUES ('006');
INSERT INTO Table1 VALUES ('024');


create table Table2(
   Id INT,
   JobNum varchar(50)
);




INSERT INTO Table2 VALUES (1,'001aed');
INSERT INTO Table2 VALUES (2,'001bef');
INSERT INTO Table2 VALUES (3,'924bac');
INSERT INTO Table2 VALUES (4,'006aab');
INSERT INTO Table2 VALUES (5,'056bcb');
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table2 t1
WHERE exists (
 select 1
 FROM Table1 t2
 WHERE t1.JobNum like CONCAT(t2.PfxJobNum ,'%')
);

| Id  | JobNum |
| --- | ------ |
| 1   | 001aed |
| 2   | 001bef |
| 4   | 006aab |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/)

Answer (score 1):

If your prefix is always the same length, I would advise:

```
select t2.*
from table2 t2
where exists (select 1
              from table1 t1
              where t1.PfxJobNum = left(t2.JobNum, 3)
             );
```

This is the preferred method, because it can take advantage of an index on `table1(PfxJobNum)`.

Not all databases support `left()`; in such cases, `substr()` or `substring()` works fine.

If the prefixes can vary in length, then use `like`:

```
select t2.*
from table2 t2
where exists (select 1
              from table1 t1
              where t2.JobNum like t1.PfxJobNum || '%'
            );
```

Not all databases use the standard `||` for string concatenation.  In those databases, use the appropriate operator.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this to work in MS Access and in MySQL 5.7.  What is the difference between this and `WHERE EXISTS(...` ?

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1, Table2
WHERE Left(Table2.JobNum,3)=Table1.PfxJobNum;
```